# How to get rid of the error 'EOFError: EOF when using input() after having used sys.stdin.readlines() in a different function?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to replicate an Excel VBA macro to Python for the sake of learning a new programming language and I am stuck at a point which Google alone is not helping (I guess I do not even know what to look for). Could you please give it a try?

**What I expect the program to do:**
When running the user should be prompted with a few options and if the input is **0** then it should ask for a multi line input containing a full HTML source code from this website [Steam Tools](https://steam.tools/cards/#/freakrp)

After the input the user is expected to hit CTRL+D / CTLR+Z to confirm there is nothing else to add (*I think the problem is here, maybe it is not able to "clear" the EOF error while using input() again?*)

Then as an ouput the program should return the first 10 rows delimited by comma and create another input() to avoid the window to autoclose.

**What the issue is**:
When I run it from the desktop (double cliking  the .py file) it autocloses withouth creating the last input().

When I run it from PyCharm it runs OK and the last input remains waiting for user action. However, it does dump an error like this:

```
File "D:/Stuff/_root/py/Steam/steam_cards_manager.py", line 51, in z_parse_tbody
input('\nCopy the program output and type Back:') EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Any feedback is appreciated as I don't know if I am doing things in an easy / effcient way.

I've upload my .py file and also a sample HTML to make it easier to replicate the issue, hope it helps.

https://github.com/brmenezewe/db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I had to replace the CTRL+D shortcut by a "trigger" word that when sent via a single input() it breaks the While loop and joins the inputs previously received:

```
def z_input_lines():
    lines = []
    while True:
        line = input()
        if not line or line.lower() != "go":
            lines.append(line)
        else:
            break
    return "".join(lines)
```